# Printing with CUPS sends signal, but doesn't print

Tags: debian, printing, cups

After I initially setup Debian, I installed CUPS so that I could print. I have a Brother MFC-9120CN, which I setup following the Debian [printing instructions](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemPrinting). After it was setup, I printed 1 or 2 pages. I hadn't tried to print for while after that, and then one day I tried to print something and it didn't work.

I tried to fix it by deleting the printer and then adding it again, but that didn't work. I have tried various protocols, which didn't work. I also tried scanning with `nmap` to see if I could find it on the network and see all of the available printing ports. I also tried `ping`ing it, which also worked.

The weirdest part about all of this, is that the printer is for sure getting a signal, because the printer's LCD backlight is coming on when I try to print anything. The CUPS job history even shows that the print jobs "completed".

The only thing that I can think of, is that something changed after cups initially started, because that is the only time I was able to print. I feel like my printer is trolling me. Does anybody know if there might be something that I haven't tried?

**Update:**
I tried reinstalling CUPS. The printer still gets a signal. It will actually start making a warm up sound.You can tell it's about to print, but it doesn't. It's like my printer actually has something personally against Linux. Please help.

Comment: Does the printer work from another OS?

Comment: And you said you could print before, did you try printing the exact same document that you printed before now?

Comment: @texasflood You can print to the printer over the network from Windows just fine. I don't know what document I printed, but I have tried printing test pages as well as printing a PNG image (which is probably the same type of file that I printed before).

Comment: Any luck with the issue? Seems very similar to [my problem](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307515/22339). It seems like some internal buffer gets filled or so, so the printer succeeds for smaller documents, but fails for larger ones.

Comment: @PetrPudlák Luck is all that I had. It automagically fixed itself. One thing I would like to mention is that other computers on my network could print to it without problems when I had this issue.

Comment: @AidanMueller Interesting, I'll try out other machines too. But my printer is USB, so it needs to be connected to a single one at a time.

Comment: @PetrPudlák I would recommend trying some windows machines if you can.