# Printing silently fails for larger documents

Tags: printing, cups

I installed the [official drivers](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=hl1110_us_eu_as) for an USB Brother HL-1110 printer. Printing works, but only for somewhat smaller files. Printing a larger PDF file, for example one that contains bigger images, silently fails without any message. The printer is receiving something, it makes a soft "hiccup" sound, but that's it. CUPS shows the document as successfully printet. What could be the cause? Where to look for debugging info?

Comment: Not knowing the printer type you are using, this is just my guess. When your document printout fills up all the memory on the printer itself, it might be pushing the print data out of printer's buffer, before it is getting printed

Comment: @MelBurslan I wrote the printer model, what more information might be helpful? Your idea sounds very plausible, but then the question is why this happens and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is the driver itself. 
I've had this issue and others as well (this kind of "silent fails" when trying to print through the network).
The only workaround I've found so far is printing through a Windows 7 vm with the Windows version of the driver installed, that way it prints just fine. 
Using Virtualbox the printer can be accessed from them vm by enabling USB controller in the vm options (this requires having the extension pack installed).
Regards.